# My Logitech H390 USB headset has always played in stereo, but today it is mono

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, logitech

Ubuntu 22.04 desktop on a Dell tower.

I have a Logitech H390 headset plugged into a front USB port.  I have tried different ports with no change.

This headset has always played sound in stereo, but I noticed today that it is mono.  If I go to Settings->Sound and test the front left and front right, both of them play in both ears.

I noticed this when suddenly youtube videos played with hardly any sound.

EDIT:  Sound in general is just terrible.  In addition to being mono, it is also severely muffled.

I am not sure when the problem started, but a couple of days ago I know it was playing music correctly.  I keep this system up to date regularly and reboot it anytime there is a kernel or initramfs change.  I suspect that one of the package updates I did recently has somehow broken pulseaudio.

I found mention of `pavucontrol`, installed it and ran it, and I could see there that the channels are locked together.  I clicked the lock to change that, and it showed left and right once I did that... but I did not see any kind of "apply" or "save" button.  It made no difference.

The kernel I am running is 6.1.0-1023-oem.

EDIT: Booting to 6.1.0-1022-oem did not change anything.

What steps can I take to find and solve this problem?

Comment: When I say the sound is muffled in addition to being mono... it's like somebody fiddled with a graphic equalizer using settings like this so the high end and low end are nonexistent and the midrange is below normal:

https://imgur.com/a/Jm8rT6i